# How to merge two layers of different shapes for an LSTM input?

Tags: python-3.x, merge, keras-layer

I would like to combine outputs of 2 different layers in my network, as follows:

```
l1.shape
TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(10), Dimension(100)])
l2.shape
TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(20), Dimension(30)])
```

I would like to combine the layers `l1` and `l2` then feed them to a bi-LSTM layer. I tried the "Concatenate" layer, but it doesn't work. I want something that could pad the layer with lower last dimension to get the same dimension as the other layer. ie: padding the last dimension of `l2` two get the following:

```
l2_padded = some_function(l2, axis=-1, dim=l1.shape[-1])
l2_padded.shape
TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(20), Dimension(100)])
```

Then perform the concatenation,

```
c = Concatenate(axis=1)([l1, l2_padded])
c.shape
TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(30), Dimension(100)])
bilstm = Bidirectional(LSTM(100))(c)
# other layers ...
```

Could you give some example and/or references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`reshape`](https://keras.io/backend/#reshape) and [`ZeroPadding1D`](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#zeropadding1d):

```
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.layers import ZeroPadding1D

x1 = Input(shape=(10, 100))
x2 = Input(shape=(20, 30))
x2_padded = K.reshape(
    ZeroPadding1D((0, x1.shape[2] - x2.shape[2]))(
        K.reshape(x2, (-1, x2.shape[2], x2.shape[1]))
    ),
    (-1, x2.shape[1], x1.shape[2])
)
```

It looks a bit clunky but unfortunately the `ZeroPadding1D` doesn't allow for specifying a padding axis and will always use `axis=1`. Same for [`K.transpose`](https://keras.io/backend/#transpose) which, unlike Numpy, does not provide a way to specify the axes that should be swapped (hence using `reshape`).